# Photoshop action to make 1 random layer visible within each group

Tags: photoshop, photoshop-script

I'm trying to use Photoshop actions to generate randomized images that are composed of a random sampling of layers.  I have 3 groups of layers which are ALL not visible by default.

1. Within each group I'd like to make 1 random layer visible (in total there will be 3 "on" layers)
2. Export the whole thing as a .png file.
3. Repeat n times

Example Groups/Layers:

```
[FRUITS]
* [Apples]
* [Oranges]
* [Pears]
* [Bananas]
* [Kiwis]

[VEGGIES]
* [Asparagus]
* [Cilantro]
* [Eggplant]

[MEATS]
* [Beef]
* [Pork]
```

All layers are hidden by default, but when I play an action, I might get the following result (visible layers):

```
Image1: [Apples] [Eggplant] [Pork]
Image2: [Pears] [Asparagus] [Pork]
Image3: [Kiwis] [Cilantro] [Beef]
```

Comment: I don't think this can be done with actions alone -- you'll probably need scripting. Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55839953/edit) to let us know what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here Is my script, but don't forget to do the following steps before running it:

1. Hide All Layers and Groups Except Background.
2. Save Your PSD.
3. Close and then reopen.

Now you are ready to rock.

**Features**

- Make Unlimited Patterns you want from your groups.
- Saved All Patterns As Indexed separate PNG in Separate Folder named `PNG`.

Watch GIF (below) to understand more:

[image]

```js
function Visible() {
  var Grps = app.activeDocument.layerSets; // loops through all groups
  for(var i = 0; i < Grps.length; i++){
    var tmp = app.activeDocument.layerSets[i].layers.length;
    app.activeDocument.layerSets[i].visible=true;
    var groupChildArr = app.activeDocument.layerSets[i].layers;
    var randLays = Math.floor(Math.random() * tmp);
    groupChildArr[randLays].visible = true;
    Save();
  }
  Revert();
}

function Save() {
  var outFolder = app.activeDocument; // psd name
  var outPath = outFolder.path;
  var fName = "PNG";   // define folder name
  var f = new Folder(outPath + "/" + fName);
  if ( ! f.exists ) {
    f.create()
  }
  var saveFile = new File(outPath + "/" + fName +"/" + "Pattern_" +  num + ".png");
  pngSaveOptions = new PNGSaveOptions();
  pngSaveOptions.interlaced = false;
  app.activeDocument.saveAs(saveFile, pngSaveOptions, true, Extension.LOWERCASE);
}

// Original code - revert function does not work
// for some users
//function Revert(){
//  var idslct = charIDToTypeID( "slct" );
//  var desc300 = new ActionDescriptor();
//  var idnull = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
//  var ref163 = new ActionReference();
//  var idSnpS = charIDToTypeID( "SnpS" );
//  ref163.putName( idSnpS, "test.psd" );
//  desc300.putReference( idnull, ref163 );
//  executeAction( idslct, desc300, DialogModes.NO );
//}

function Revert(){
   var idRvrt = charIDToTypeID( "Rvrt" );
   executeAction( idRvrt, undefined, DialogModes.NO );
}

var count = prompt("How many patterns you want","");
for (var x=0 ; x<count;x++){
  var num = x+1;
  Visible();
}
```