# Photoshop action to make 1 random layer visible within each group - good script but there is a bug

Tags: photoshop-script

i've tried this awesome script and its exactly what i need !! Congrats to the developers !!

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55860891/15896945

But i have a bug... Photoshop 21.2.4 (on mac os 10.14.2) give me this message (my psd version is in french, so the message is translate in english):

Error 8800: A general Photoshop error has occurred. This feature may not be available in this version of Photoshop.

The “Select” command is not available. Line: 36 -> executeAction (idslct, desc300, DialogModes.NO);
and the script generate one and only pattern, i've tried all the psd version that i have till V5.1, i have the same error on each version ...

Any advices ? THX

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting the bug is the the revert function is specific to the coder's initial "test.psd"

Try replacing the Revert function with:

```
function Revert()
{
   var idRvrt = charIDToTypeID( "Rvrt" );
   executeAction( idRvrt, undefined, DialogModes.NO );
}
```

And you should be good to go!

... But now I'm getting the weirdest feeling on déjà vu.

Comment: Many thanks ! It works !!
i did saw you did the same correction to a similar code:
"Script to make 1 random layer visible within each group [Photoshop cc2018]"
and i tried this script but it didn't work...
Is it possible to add your correction to the initial code for futur users ?