# Illustrator script (or action) to make 1 random layer visible per group

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-scriptui

Similar to this question but with adobe Illustrator: [Photoshop action to make 1 random layer visible within each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55839953/photoshop-action-to-make-1-random-layer-visible-within-each-group)

I want to use an illustrator script (or action) to generate images that are composed of a random sampling of grouped layers.

1. With in each of the 12 groups, I want to make 1 layer per group visible.
2. Export the visible layers as an svg. Bonus points if I can change the file format.
3. Repeat the process n times

I know this is similar to the code linked above though I want to be able to use illustrator instead of photoshop if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be something like this:

```js
function main() {
    var doc = app.activeDocument;

    // hide all items
    var i = doc.pageItems.length;
    while(i--) doc.pageItems[i].hidden = true;

    // show one random item on every layer
    var i = doc.layers.length;
    while(i--) { 
        var items = doc.layers[i].pageItems;
        var index = Math.round(Math.random()*(items.length-1));
        items[index].hidden = false;
    }

    // save svg
    var counter = 0;
    var file = File(Folder.desktop + '/' + counter + '.svg') ;
    while (file.exists) {
        file = File(Folder.desktop + '/' + counter++ + '.svg');
    }
    doc.exportFile(file, ExportType.SVG);

    // save png
    var counter = 0;
    var file = File(Folder.desktop + '/' + counter + '.png') ;
    while (file.exists) {
        file = File(Folder.desktop + '/' + counter++ + '.png');
    }
    var options = new ExportOptionsPNG24();
    options.artBoardClipping = true;
    doc.exportFile(file, ExportType.PNG24, options);
}

// repeat the script N times
var n = 3;
while(n--) main();
```

It hides all the page items, shows one random item on every layer, and saves the document as SVG and PNG in the desktop folder.